# How to Reference campaign object from Lead?

Tags: apex, soql, soap-api, leads, campaign

Salesforce Enterprise WSDL downloaded from my organization shows that there is Campaign reference on Lead object:

```
    <complexType name="Lead">
        <complexContent>
            <extension base="ens:sObject">
                <sequence>
                <element name="Campaign" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" type="ens:Campaign"/>
```

Screenshot from Lead object:

[image]

And I don't see the campaign reference on this [page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm)

When I run the below query :

```
SELECT Id,Campaign.Id FROM Lead
```

This is the error, it throws:

> No such relation 'Campaign' on entity 'Lead'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

I guess I am doing a basic mistake..Can you guys please help me on this?

Comment: Campaign and Lead are related thru Campaign Member. so we can't directly use the Campaign field. check this previous discussion for details : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47193/error-compile-error-invalid-field-campaign-for-sobject-lead