# Trigger to Tie a New Lead Back to Campaign

Tags: trigger, campaign

we are using a system that integrates with Salesforce called Hubspot that generates contacts and leads. How it works is that when a Hubspot form is filled out, the entry is brought into salesforce. If the email is not associated with any contacts in SF, it creates a leads. If the email IS associated with any contacts, it just updates that existing contact (and ties it to the realted salesforce campaign. I have created a Process Builder process that makes it so whenever one of these contacts is tied to a campaign, that a lead is automatically generated. (The goals is to only have leads coming in from this form).

Since "Campaign" is a lookup field on leads, I am having trouble making so the newly generated lead is associated with the desired campaign. I have not been able to finda way to populate the "Campaign" field on the new leads with a campaign. I have begun a trigger to try and and insert a new lead and campaign member for that new lead but it is coming together poorly and does not work.

```
trigger LeadGenfromCampaignMember on CampaignMember (after insert) {

CampaignMember cpm = Trigger.new[0];    
Lead newLead = new Lead(FirstName = cpm.Contact.FirstName, LastName = cpm.Contact.LastName, Email = cpm.Contact.Email);    
CampaignMember newcpm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cpm.CampaignId, LeadId = newLead.Id);



if (cpm.Campaign.Provider_Sales_Campaign__c == True){
        insert newLead;
        insert newcpm;
}
```

}

Comment: Is the incoming CampaignMember has leadId filled already filled-in? or may be it already has contactId already filled-in. The documentation says, campaignMember can have either LeadId or contactId.

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/47193/error-compile-error-invalid-field-campaign-for-sobject-lead Please refer this and let us know if you still have questions..I can definitely help you out on this.

Comment: You have many issues here: bulkification, referencing data you haven't queried, order of operations, etc. It needs quite a bit of help.

Comment: The incoming CampaignMember should only have a contact ID. I am trying to create a brand new Lead and a separate new campaign member for that Lead. The incoming campaign member should only have an associated contact but the new lead should be tied to the campaign with a new campaign member

Comment: Yes it does need quite a bit of help I have not written triggers for SFDC before this.

Comment: @sfdcfox when you say that I am referencing data that I have not queried, are you referring to the "cpm.Contact.etc"? I am starting over trying to bulkify this but I am looking to see if that should be included

Comment: @ChrisP Feel free to read my answer. Comments included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trigger LeadGenfromCampaignMember on CampaignMember (after insert) {
    // Determine initial eligibility
    CampaignMember[] processed = new CampaignMember[0];
    for(CampaignMember record: Trigger.new) {
        if(record.ContactId != null) {
            processed.add(record);
        }
    }
    // Quit if no contacts present
    if(processed.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    // Find eligible campaigns
    Set<Id> campaignIds = new Map<Id, Campaign>(
        [SELECT Id FROM Campaign WHERE Id IN (SELECT CampaignId FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id IN :processed) AND Provider_Sales_Campaign__c = TRUE]
    ).keySet();
    // Quit if no campaigns are eligible
    if(campaignIds.isEmpty()) {
        return;
    }
    // Load associated contacts
    Map<Id, Contact> contacts = new Map<Id, Contact>(
        [SELECT FirstName, LastName, Email, Account.Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM CampaignMember WHERE Id IN :processed)]
    );
    // Create new Leads, store temporary members
    CampaignMember[] members = new CampaignMember[0];
    Lead[] leads = new Lead[0];
    for(CampaignMember record: Trigger.new) {
        if(contacts.containsKey(record.ContactId) && campaignIds.contains(record.CampaignId)) {
            Contact contactRecord = contacts.get(record.ContactId);
            leads.add(new Lead(FirstName=contactRecord.FirstName, LastName=contactRecord.LastName, Email=contactRecord.Email, Company=contactRecord.Account.Name));
            members.add(new CampaignMember(Campaignid=record.CampaignId, MemberStatus='Sent'));
        }
    }
    insert leads;
    // Associate temporary members with newly created leads
    for(Integer index = 0, size = leads.size(); index < size; index++) {
        members[index].LeadId = leads[index].Id;
    }
    insert members;
}
```

Comment: This worked EXQUISITELY @sfdcfox anything I can do to help boost reputation, rank, etc. I am happy to. I am testing this in our sandbox and it is working well on every front.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that :

You are trying to get the Lead Id before it is inserted to database.
Please see the below corrected code:

```
    trigger LeadGenfromCampaignMember on CampaignMember (after insert) {

    CampaignMember cpm = Trigger.new[0];    
    Lead newLead = new Lead(FirstName = cpm.Contact.FirstName, LastName = cpm.Contact.LastName, Email = cpm.Contact.Email);
    insert newLead; //This line is missing..If you do not insert, you don't get the Id    
    CampaignMember newcpm = new CampaignMember(CampaignId = cpm.CampaignId, LeadId = newLead.Id);



    if (cpm.Campaign.Provider_Sales_Campaign__c == True){
            insert newLead;
            insert newcpm;
    }
    }
```

But as sfdcfox pointed out you should definitely bulkify the trigger.