# Invalid field CampaignId for SObject Lead

Tags: trigger

I created a custom lookup field in my Account object named Campaign__c. I am trying to map the standard Campaign field from the Lead object to this one. But I am getting this error `Invalid field CampaignId for SObject Lead` in my trigger. Meanwhile, here's my trigger:

**updateField**

```
trigger UpdateField on Lead (after insert, after update) {
    List<Account> accsToUpdate = new List<Account>();
    for(Lead lead1 : Trigger.New){
        Account tempAcc = new Account(Id = lead1.ConvertedAccountId);
        if(tempAcc.Campaign__c != lead1.CampaignId){
            tempAcc.Campaign__c = lead1.CampaignId;
            accsToUpdate.add(tempAcc);            
        }
    }
    update accsToUpdate;
}
```

Comment: In the schema level, there is no field named CampaignId in [Lead](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_lead.htm) object.
Here's an [article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000205967&language=en_US) about it.

Also link to @cropredy's [answer](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/47199/20830) which helps you to understand what happens behind the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Campaign field in Lead is not accessible through SOQL. For this you need to do use CampaignMember.

```
    trigger UpdateField on Lead (after insert, after update) 
    {
        Map<ID, ID> CampaignIDs= new Map<ID, ID>();
        List<Account> accsToUpdate = new List<Account>(); 

        List<CampaignMember> cms = [SELECT CampaignID, LeadID, Status FROM CampaignMember WHERE LeadID in : Trigger.new]; 

        for(CampaignMember cm:cms)
        { 
            if(!CampaignIDs.containsKey(cm.LeadID))
            { 
                CampaignIDs.put(cm.LeadID, cm.CampaignID); 
            }
        }

        for(Lead lead1 : Trigger.New)
        {
            Account tempAcc = new Account(Id = lead1.ConvertedAccountId);
            if(tempAcc.Campaign__c != CampaignIDs.get(lead1.Id)){
                tempAcc.Campaign__c = CampaignIDs.get(lead1.Id);
                accsToUpdate.add(tempAcc);            
            }
        }
        update accsToUpdate;
   }
```

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: glad it works for you :). @Praveen: links suggested by you are very useful.